# My Umbraco Forms not working properly umbraco 7.4.0

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, umbraco7

I am using Umbraco 7.4.0. When I installed Umbraco Forms 4.2.1 in my project that working fine.
After that I created contact form, subscriber form.
But when I committed my changes by Tortoise Git, then completely work on server.
But after any other person committed any changes from the Tortoise Git and that changed I get that time not show my contact and subscriber form.
When I again install Umbraco Form 4.2.1 that will work but my subscriber form not show.

So, please any know what happens in that ?

Comment: where is your git repository? only one repository?

Comment: Bit bucket repository used. And yes only one repository.